# Why does my code run from the dashboard, but not when I assign a script to a button?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm not an engineer so I hope I can adequately explain my problem.

I am currently using Google Apps Script to write a simple Google Sheets tool for work. Earlier this evening I chose to "Make a Copy" of my file, as a backup. After that, when I tried to load the Script Editor I was asked if I wanted to load the original or the backup. I chose the original, because that's the one I was continuing to work on.

Unfortunately, I have a button on my Sheet that seemed to be pointing at the backup script, and not the script I was working on. I know this because I was getting an error that existed in the backup, but I FIXED it in the new version. After some research I figured out how to load the backup script and delete it. Now I no longer have to choose a file, and I thought everything was fixed.

The problem now is that when I try to run my code by clicking on the button, it just hangs. If I run or debug my code from the Script Editor it works as it should. Is my button perhaps pointing to a non-existent script? (The one I deleted.)

Is there a way to tell? Or could the problem be something else?

Thank you.

Comment: I guess I'd try reassigning to the new script.

Comment: Does deleting the button and creating it again solve the issue?